# Enable horizontal swipe in hammer.js

Tags: jquery, touch, hammer.js

I have an unordered list of elements in my HTML. I have added a touch handler for each of the individual list elements to do something if the user taps on a list element.

```
elementToTriggerTouch.hammer().on('tap', function(e) {
    do_something();
}
```

The tap handler works fine. However, it disables the swipe functionality in the horizontal direction.

How can I override touch event handler with swipe, when the event is a swipe event?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to get the horizontal in hammer documenttation. [HammerJS](http://hammerjs.github.io/examples/)

Maybe you can try with another function, like as swipe:

```
$sw.on('swipe', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.direction == 'left' || event.direction == 'right'){
        $('#ns-tool-bar, #left-content').toggleClass('slide');
    }
});
```